# I have no idea what is happening to my Mac mini

Tags: mac-mini

It keeps flashing between the Apple logo, a folder with a question mark and a  symbol.

It won’t turn on properly and I've tried going into recovery mode did not work. I tried leaving it alone for a day and coming back which did not work. I have tried looking up methods to fix it but I don’t know if they will result in erased data.

It is a Mac mini late 2012.

Comment: Have you try doing Reset Smc : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295 and Reset Nvram :  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Comment: Can you elaborate on "tried going into recovery mode did not work"? Which steps did you perform and what was the result?